# system takes up 50 GB of storage

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I'm working on a mac and since I've updated to High Sierra, the system takes up more and more space for no reason. I've found out that most of the times the problem comes with time machine, but I never used this program and there was no other solution to fix that problem. Now, I'm running out of space. Thanks for help!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Initially system is allocated all the space and then as you leave the window up, I get updates that carve out each category and then the system grows less. If you log out and log back in, does system still show 48.69 and then if you leave it up for 30 minutes idle (not sleeping) does the number change?

Answer (score 1):

The value that you see listed includes many things we wouldn't consider part of the system. If I do the same on my machine it says System is talking about 130 GB. If I run DaisyDisk on my drive it says System is taking 9.8 GB. You can download [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) and see what's taking up space. DaisyDisk is not free but they offer a free trial.